# A question about tensor product

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

If $A$ is an algebra, $M_{n}(A)$ denotes the algebra of all $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $A$. The operations are defined just as for scalar matrices. If $A$ is a *-algebra, so is $M_{n}(A)$, where the involution is given by $(a_{ij})^{\ast}=(a_{ji}^{\ast})$.

**Thus $M_{n}(A)$ may be identified with (the algebraic tensor product) $A\otimes M_{n}(A)$.**

My question is how to explain that $M_{n}(A)$ can be identified with (the algebraic tensor product) $A\otimes M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: It should be $A\otimes M_n(\mathbb{C})$, not $A\otimes M_n(A)$

Comment: @ Prahlad Vaidyanathan: Yes, you are right. Could you explain this to me more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a map
$$
\varphi : A\times M_n(\mathbb{C}) \to M_n(A)
$$
given by
$$
\varphi(a,(\lambda_{i,j})) := (\lambda_{i,j}a)
$$
This is bilinear, and so induces a linear map from the algebraic tensor product
$$
\varphi : A\otimes M_n(\mathbb{C}) \to M_n(A)
$$
It is easy to see that this map is bijective, and a *-homomorphism.

Comment: Thanks, Prahlad Vaidyanathan ~